# MainActivity is not an enclosing class - In Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want make a listview with a search function.

I have found this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/.

I didn't use an activity but a fragment.

I have a problem on this :

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
}
```

> Error : com.XX.XX.MainActivity is not an enclosing class.

I think the problem is MainActivity.this. I never use this function in fragment.

Can you help me to resolve this please.
Thank you

Comment: Where `adapter` variable is declared? As far as I understood it is declared as an instance variable within your fragment, while `MainActivity` is another class. In such case you should be able to use it directly: `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`.

Comment: How i didn't do that alone ? Oh thank you dude :)

Comment: Ok, I write it as an answer so that you can accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where adapter variable is declared? As far as I understood it is declared as an instance variable within your fragment, while `MainActivity` is another class. In such case you should be able to use it directly: `adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);`